# Timer/trigger works only for one day C#

Tags: c#, timer, triggers, method-chaining

I made a timer function that looks like this:

```
 public Pocetna_forma()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Timer_reset(new TimeSpan(11, 37, 00));
    }

 private void Timer_reset(TimeSpan alertTime)
    {
        DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan timeToGo = alertTime - current.TimeOfDay;
        if (timeToGo < TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            return;//time already passed
        }
        this.reset = new System.Threading.Timer(x =>
        {
            this.Trigger_brisanje();
        }, null, timeToGo, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
    }

 private void Trigger_brisanje()
    {
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Connectionstring);
        conn.Open();

        NpgsqlCommand upis_odlaska = new NpgsqlCommand("begin;update zaposlenici set polje_stanje=1,vrijeme3=null,vrijeme2=null;commit;", conn);
        upis_odlaska.ExecuteReader();

        conn.Close();
    }
```

I noticed that my trigger runs only one day after I start the application, and that application is running 24/7 on the server, so its never shut down. I need it to run every day of the week, some ideas where is the catch to do this?

Comment: Seems like this would be better accomplished as a scheduled task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final argument you give for your Timer constructor is Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan - however checking the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) the arguments are:

```
public Timer(
  TimerCallback callback,
  object state,
  TimeSpan dueTime,
  TimeSpan period
)
```

i.e. The last argument should be the repetition period. 
Because you've supplied an infinite period, the timer will never trigger again.

If this is daily it should be something like TimeSpan.FromHours(24.0).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this following code snippet instead of a timer:

```
 public static async Task FireTrigger(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
    {
        do
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Hour == hours && DateTime.Now.Minute == minutes && DateTime.Now.Second == seconds)
            {
                // Call trigger!

            }
            await Task.Delay(990);
        }
        while (true);
    }
```

And you can call it like:

```
 Task.Run(async () => await FireTrigger(hours, minutes, seconds));
```

It's an async task. It don't block your other code and it runs only 1 time per second, but it runs everytime.